# Accessing Each Item in a For Loop using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to build a full stack application using express and mongoose in the backend. I will provide an image to explain my aim more clearer.
[image: UI]

My problem is I can't get a hold of which one of the "chain"s + or - button is clicked so I can decrease the count of trophy icons by one for that specific chain. For this I've created a hidden input in the form, prodiving me the value of the chain name but I am not sure how I can get the specific chain, as these chain names and "streaks"(number of trophies to be displayed) are stored in an array. I hope I was clear explaining my question.

--POST route for the form--

```
app.post("/chain", function (req, res) {
  const newChainName = req.body.newChain;
  const currentChainName = req.body.submit;
  const clickedChain = req.body.secret;
  if (req.body.submit === "add") {
    User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, foundUser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (foundUser) {
        foundUser.chains.push({
          chainName: newChainName,
          streak: 1,
        });
        foundUser.save(function () {
          res.redirect("/chain");
        });
      }
    });
  } else if (req.body.submit === "increase") {
    Chain.findOne({ chainName: clickedChain }, function (err, foundChain) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (foundChain) {
        console.log(req.body.secret); //DOESN'T LOG ANYTHING
        //INCREASE STREAK BY 1
        // foundChain.save(function () {
        //   res.redirect("/chain");
        // });
      }
    });
  } else if (req.body.submit === "decrease") {
    Chain.findOne({ chainName: clickedChain }, function (err, foundChain) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (foundChain) {
        console.log(req.body.secret); //DOESN'T LOG ANYTHING
        //DECREASE STREAK BY 1
        // foundChain.save(function () {
        //   res.redirect("/chain");
        // });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

So this is a single HTML form, and when you click "Add New Chain" button I create a new "chain" containing + and - buttons and a title. When + or - buttons are clicked I'd like to add or delete those trophy icons you can see. I grab the Chain Name value and save it into the User Schema and display it in HTML using a for loop with EJS, no problems so far. I have tried giving + and - buttons values, so I can tell which one is clicked and create functionality accordingly. However I cannot get a hold of the specific "chain" that has been clicked, I can only get all the chains as an array.

This is what the HTML form and my DB structure looks like.

--The form--

```
<form id="chain-form" action="/chain" method="POST">
    <div class="row chain-main">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input
          name="newChain"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Chain Name"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" value="add">Add New Chain</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chains-wrapper">
      <div class="my-chains">
        <%userChains.forEach((chain, index) => { %>
        <h5 class="chain-header">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="decrease"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></button> 
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="increase"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
          <input name="secret" type="hidden" value="<%=chain.chainName%>"></input>
          <span><%=chain.chainName%></span>
          <span>
            <%for(i=0; i<chain.streak; i++){ %>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-trophy"></i>
            <%}%>
            <%});%>
          </span>
        </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

--DB structure--

```
const chainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  chainName: String,
  streak: Number,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  pomodoroStreak: Number,
  chains: [chainSchema],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well after hours of trying I figured out why it was returning an array instead of an object when I tried to log the corresponding "chain" when a + or - button is clicked. I put the forEach loop inside the form, so it was looping through each item, then returning all the values collected as an array. I wrapped a seperate form with the loop, now I am able to get each "chain" as an object when + or - buttons are clicked.

Thank you myself huehue.